# How to get the relationship between a result and a data

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, machine-learning-model

I have big data (at least 10 variables each row and millions of lines) and result (for example if y=0.2 and x=0.4 and z=0.9 so there is a system failure).
I need to find the relationship between the data to result (let the system alone learn the connections that led to the result) with machine learning.

Where should I start, which models should be studied?
Is it deep learning?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to predict failures vs non-failures based on those ten variables? Do you have the observations about failures vs non-failures?

Answer (score 0):

Try training a [Decision Tree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html) model: these are interpretable ML models that provide if-then conditions on variables, moreover DTs are very suitable for tabular data.

If look for better performance go for *Random forests*, or *Extra trees* (still DT based) which also provide feature importance but you loose interpretability.

If you find quite low performance with DT or RF, try a Deep learning classifier (e.g. a feed-forward neural network) but forget about understanding the relationship between predictions and input features..